# all_products[] Not working with JSON variable

Tags: json, shopify, liquid

I am trying to retrieve a metafield with all_products[] but using a locale json file content as the handle.
I have created this value in the en.default.json. If I just use {{'products.product.product_handle'  | t}} I receive the proper handle so I know that I'm getting the right information but for whatever reason I can't pass that value into the all_products[] function.

I've tried the following code:

{{all_products[ 'products.product.product_handle'  | t ].metafields.my_fields.cardtext}}

and

{% assign text = 'products.product.product_handle'  | t  %}
{{all_products[text]..metafields.my_fields.cardtext}}

Json Setup:
"product_handle": "{{ handle }}"

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or if there is another way to display this content?

Answer (score 0):

The first syntax is invalid.

The second syntax is almost valid, you have double dots before metafields => `..metafields`

So when you fix the above as long as you are targeting the correct translatable string and metafield it should work:

```
{% assign text = 'products.product.product_handle' | t %} 
{{all_products[text].metafields.my_fields.cardtext}}
```

You can check if you are getting the product first, for example:

```
{{all_products[text].id}}
```

If you are getting the product but not the metafield, then the issue might be in the metafield target.

Comment: I have used .title to check if I'm getting anything and I'm not. Also This is how I've setup the JSON:
"product_handle": "{{ handle }}"

Comment: @BenPinalesBrightBridge I'm assuming you are using the `locales/en.default.json` and you are not trying to create a custom JSON somewhere else, right? From your translatable string, you are expecting a variable to be passed to replace the handle, so you should pass the variable to it `{% assign text = 'products.product.product_handle' | t: handle: YOUR_PRODUCT_HANDLE %} `... this makes no sense since you can pass the handle directly in the code and not use translatable string... but I'm not sure what is your exact idea.